# Multi-partition USB drive

Tags: partitioning, bootable-media, usb-storage

Is it possible to with any linux or windows software partition a USB drive and be able to while maintaining the data stored on one partition, overwrite another with something like an iso? Could i then boot from the one i overwrote?

Comment: Have you tried to partionned? Does it work?

Comment: You're making it a lot more complicated that it must be. Ventoy can make bootable USB media to which all you need to add is the ISO itself or more than one and yes, you can also make folders and use the drive as any other mass storage device.

Comment: USB drives ought to be considered as only containing temporary data. If you can't risk losing the data on it… it probably means you don't have a copy elsewhere. That's just an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: The drive is for setting up or resetting a computer. It will contain an ISO for the os installer and data i will defenetley need (such as ssh keys).

Comment: You don't actually need to use partitions for this. There is software specifically for a stick that allows you to put isos in one partition, and then directly boot into any of them as if it were the only iso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a solution myself: Getting another USB-Stick!! Before that, i will probably not reset my computer, as my current setup works.

Comment: Good idea! BTW, since I like to keep installation and imaging apps for a number of OS's, µSD cards are *cheap* and *conveniently stored*.  Get a few card readers and many cards. Same also applies to storing music for use when traveling - one genre or composer per card.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to accomplish your goal, "It will contain an ISO for the os installer and data i (sic) will defenetley (sic) need (such as ssh keys)," (which should have been included in the question).

- A [persistent](https://www.maketecheasier.com/persistent-live-usb-vs-full-install-usb/) live instance on USB, such as [Ubuntu Live with persistence](https://www.howtogeek.com/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) or [Hasleo WinToUsb](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html). This uses a USB drive to both boot and to hold data. Use it as you would an internal drive, such as installing software, storing driver packages and data.

  *Caveat*: Many USB drives are exceedingly  *s l o w* to write data compared even to HDD. Expect the user experience to be lethargic on such drives.
- Create a bootable USB with a separate partition for data storage, then install the bootable operating system. Simply use any disk management tool, such as [gparted](https://gparted.org/) or [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), to add a partition or two to the USB. One advantage of using an additional partition for data storage is that it can be formatted differently from the boot partition, which would likely be FAT32 so that BIOS can read it. This may allow faster access to data than with a persistent OS, but changes made during use of the OS, such as installing tools, would not be saved.

Comment: The bootable part is to install an os and will change, can i with any method overwrite this part with an iso without losing data? Also, can you more clearly explain how to do the second method?

Comment: There is no way I'd recommend to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the USB drive is already bootable, you can simply open the iso file and drag and drop (copy) the files to the USB drive. No need to reflash or delete data if it's already formatted correctly and bootable. Just make sure not to have files with the same name as the installation files on the USB stick already (sources, support, efi, boot, autorun.inf, setup.exe, bootmgr, bootmgr.efi).